# Горячие клавиши в TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу создать горячую клавишу для текстбокса (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> для выделения)? Стандартно - не работает.
Есть ли событие, которое подойдет для реализации поставленной задачи?

Comment: Интересный факт, даже специально проверил. Действительно, Ctrl + A и некоторые другие сочетания перестают работать сразу после переключения TextBox в режим MultyLine. В одно-строчном режиме все сочетания работают как положено, поэтому я сначала даже удивился вопросу. На MSDN о различиях в поведении обработки клавиш ни слова, раскопки продолжаются...

Answer (score 4):

Подробный ответ тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913498/select-all-shortcut-fails-when-multiline-property-is-true/15915059#15915059

Для ленивых:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.A)) {
        textBox1.SelectAll();
        //убираем звуковое сопровождение при нажатии клавиш
        e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

В версии фреймворка 4.6.1 обещали исправить. Экспериментально проверил, работает как положено.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CorrectTextBoxes(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub CorrectTextBoxes(Base As Control)
    If Base.Controls IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each Ctrl As Control In Base.Controls
            CorrectTextBoxes(Ctrl)
            Dim Txt As TextBox = TryCast(Ctrl, TextBox)
            If Txt IsNot Nothing Then
                AddHandler Txt.KeyDown, AddressOf Txt_KeyDown
            End If
        Next Ctrl
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Txt_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A And e.Control Then CType(sender, TextBox).SelectAll()
End Sub
```

http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=43995&p=6763394#p6763394

Comment: Visual basic что ли?

Comment: @DmitryShulga, VB.NET. Зато делает ровно то, что ты спросил - обработка Ctrl+A в текстовых полях. Один раз написал и при необходимости в своих программах использую :) На шарпе так же будет.

Comment: @DmitryShulga, http://converter.telerik.com/ - конвертер между шарпом и бейсиком.

Comment: получилось, все ок - работает, но при зажатии Ctrl + A также появляется и системный звук. Тот звук, что, например, возникает, когда нажать в другое место, когда включен показ формы ShowDialog(); Как этот звук можно вырубить?