# Звук при нажатии горячих клавиш

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl+А</kbd>. При нажатии все работает, как я  хотел, но проигрывается стандартный звук «Восклицание». Откуда он берется и как его устранить?

Я заметил что при запуске формы у меня в фокусе текстбокс. И если сделать его неактивным звук пропадает.

Comment: Вы бы привели воспроизводящий пример, а то получается какой-то подземный стук.

Comment: @VladD Воспроизводиться системный звук "Восклицание"

Comment: @VladD  я заметил что при запуске формы у меня в фокусе текстбокс. И если сделать его неактивным звук пропадает. Как убрать фокус с тестбокса при запуске?

Comment: Ну, поставьте фокус на что-нибудь ещё?

Comment: Не, это не воспроизводящий пример. Нужно что-то такое, чтобы другие участники смогли запустить и увидеть ту же проблему на своей машине. [mcve]

Comment: @VladD не, все нормально, это известный баг со звуком в текстбоксе. Там еще с горячими клавишами проблема.

Comment: У вас какая версия фреймворка в проекте выставлена? `TextBox.MultyLine = true` ? Посмотрите тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479523/198316

Comment: @rdorn: Ох, не знал. Тогда имеет смысл опубликовать ответ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TextBox` - наиболее часто используемый элемент WinForms, прямую конкуренцию может составить только `Label`. И именно в нем есть досадный баг, который исправили только в .NET 4.6.1

Почти все контролы, когда они находятся в фокусе, перехватывают на себя обработку нажатий на клавиши и передают событие родительскому контейнеру, только если это явно указать в обработчике. В `TextBox` по-умолчанию определено много горячих клавиш для работы именно с ним, но если он находится в режиме `MultyLine`, то большинство сочетаний клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>some key</kbd> работают некорректно. Если быть точным, то единственное что отрабатывает для этих сочетаний - это проигрывание системного звука "Восклицание" (не помню как он называется в английской версии), который обычно сигнализирует об ошибочном действии пользователя (например при клике в основное окно приложения, при открытом модальном диалоге).

<strike>Решений два, радикальное и "костыль".</strike>
Решений три:

**Мягкое решение** - добавить на форму `MenuStrip` и настроить горячие клавиши в `MenuStripItem`-ах. Меню перехватит все заданные сочетания, они не попадут в `TextBox`, следовательно не будет проигрываться звук. Хорошо, но подходит не всегда.

**Радикальное решение** - пересобрать проект на платформе .NET 4.6.1. В этой редакции исправили работу некоторых сочетаний клавиш, например <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (выделить всё), но поведение по-умолчанию для не используемых сочетаний клавиш не изменилось. Для нас это означает, что звуки отдельных сочетаний клавиш придется экранировать отдельно. Либо с помощью меню (см. выше), либо как описано ниже.

**Исправляем баг руками** - когда ни добавление меню, ни повышение версии платформы не допустимо, придется исправлять баг своими силами. Для этого вешаем обработчик на событие `TextBox.KeyDown`, в котором прописываем необходимые нам сочетания клавиш следующим образом (для примера <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>):

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.A)) 
    {
        textBox1.SelectAll();
        //убираем звуковое сопровождение при нажатии клавиш
        e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Отдельно замечу, что **нельзя использовать** для отключения звуков вариант:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Так как это не только заглушит звуки, но и превратит `TextBox` в тыкву, отключив обработку клавиш полностью.