# Написание sql-запроса с использованием текстовой переменной

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio

Хочу организовать автоматическое заполение textBox, через sql запрос.
В переменную sql заносится исполняемый запрос, в textBox10 - гос номер авто, по которому находятся остальные данные автомобиля.

```
    private void textBox10_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM [avto] WHERE [gosN] = '"+ textBox10.ToString() + "'";
            textBox7.Text = sql;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);

            SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
            dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                textBox7.Text = (dataReader["tabN"].ToString());
                textBox8.Text = (dataReader["marka_model"].ToString());
                string date;
                date = (dataReader["date_uchet"].ToString());
                textBox9.Text = date.Substring(0, date.Length - 7);
            }
        }
    }
```

В textBox7 для наглядности занес формируемый запрос. Результат textBox7: SELECT * FROM [avto] WHERE [gosN] = 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: У072АВ99'

После нажатия Enter заполняется только textBox7 sql-запросом, далее код не выполняется.

Comment: `textBox10.ToString()` => `textBox10.Text` ? Но вообще за такое надо бить по рукам. Используйте переметризированные звпросы.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо за подсказку, но код все равно не выпоняется дальше. Вставляется в textBox7 и все. Ошбики никакой не выдает. Только системный звук при повторном нажатии enter.

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)

Comment: У Вас ``dataReader.Read()`` будет ``false``, поскольку запрос сформирован неправильно и будет давать пустой набор записей.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается системного звука и как от него избавиться при нажатии некоторых клавиш и сочетаний в TextBox, читать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/660598/198316)

Далее исправляем запрос на рабочий и безопасный:

```cs
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM [avto] WHERE [gosN] = @param";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", textBox10.Text);
    using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        //что-то делаем с данными, если они есть
    }
}
```

В данном случае вместо склейки строки из константного текста запроса и текста вводимого пользователем, используется строго константный запрос с параметром, значение которого указывается через свойства команды. Такой запрос безопасен с точки зрения sql-инъекций, т.к. пользовательский ввод не может быть интерпретирован как функциональная часть запроса независимо от его содержания.

Отдельно обращаю внимание на то, что создавать и открывать соединение с БД лучше непосредственно перед использованием. А вот закрывать его вручную не обязательно, можно просто указать в конструкторе ридера закрытие соединения после завершения его работы.